# Smooth a Cylinder in one direction

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

I think this question is already answered anywhere, but I couldn't find a solution with my search terms :/ . 
So I got this model and I only want to smooth out the cylinder parts, but not the extruded edges.

So here is my original model, I think it's kinda clear what should be smoothed out, it is supposed to become a rifle scope.

[image: Thats the original model]

This happens with the normal smooth button, but I already tried it with a Bevel modifier and subdivison surface aswell.

[image: Thats totally not what I want]

Solution: Edge Split Modifier with Smooth:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [edge split modifier] with smooth shading to round some areas and keep sharp edges.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I searched for, I knew that the solution is kinda easy :) Thanks!