# Why I can't smooth a cylinder right in Blender?

Tags: normals

Why can't I smooth the upper cylinder like the bottom one? I tried to set the top and bottom face to Flat "Shade Flat", and set the middle face loop to "Shade Smooth". It doesn't work.

I also tried to set "Shade Smooth" to all faces of the cylinder, top and bottom edge loops set "Mark Sharp". It doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth a Cylinder in one direction](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38518/smooth-a-cylinder-in-one-direction)

Comment: Yes. But before I found this answer I found another way to resolve this task. And I decided to share this solution. But in comments says, that not a better way. So, I can delete this answer if it duplicated earlier answer by your and my link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 ways, one is to select the specific faces you want to be shaded flat and then go in the **Mesh** menu, under **Shading** and select the **Flat Faces**.

[image]

Or you select the object and go in the **Object Data Properties** under **Normals** and activate **Auto Smooth**.

The latter works very well with most objects, but does not give you as much control as the first way.

Auto Smooth demo:
[image]

Happy Blending

Comment: Second way didn't work, I tried. Thanks for the first way.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38518/smooth-a-cylinder-in-one-direction)  is the best. It's about Edge Split modifier. But I find another way.

1. Enter into Edit mode
2. Select all faces -> Alt+N -> Merge
3. Select top and bottom faces -> Alt+N -> Split

Done.

Comment: This is not the best solution since it create 1) a non-manifold mesh and 2) duplicates the number of required vertices for the edge loop that is split. This can be ok for your use case, but in general it's better to use a solution that just modifies normals and the shading.

Comment: Hmm, I didn’t pay attention to vertices count. Thanks for the information!